# Does layer normalization delay training?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

You can find my code here with the results:

https://github.com/shwe87/tfm-asr/blob/master/ASR-Spanish-Bi-RNN-17062020.ipynb

I tested two simple models for ASR in Spanish:

**Model 1:**

```
- Layer Normalization 
- Bi-directional GRU
- Dropout
- Fully Connected layer
- Dropout
- Fully Connected layer as a classifier (classifies one of the alphabet chars)
```

**Model 2:**

```
  - Conv Layer 1
  - Conv Layer 2
  - Fully Connected
  - Dropout
  - Bidirectional GRU
  - Fully connected layer as a classifier
```

I tried with 30 epochs because I have limited resources of GPU.
The validation and training loss for these two models:
[image]
Model 1 performed not so good as expected. 
Model 2 worked too well, after 20 epochs, it started overfitting (please see the graph in the notebook results) and in the output, I could actually see some words creating which seems like the labels. Although it is overfitting, it still needs training because it doesn't predict the total outcome. For start, I am happy with this model.

I tested a third complex Model.
You can find it here with the results output:

https://github.com/shwe87/tfm-asr/blob/master/ASR-DNN.ipynb

**Model 3:**

```
  - Layer Normalization
  - RELU
  - Bidirectional GRU
  - Dropout 
  - Stack this 10 times more.
```

The valid loss and training loss for this model:
[image]
I tested this on 30 epochs and there were no good results, actually, all the predictions were blank...

Is this because this complex model needs more epochs for training?

**Update:**

I modified the model by adding 2 convolutional layer before the stacked GRU and the model seems to have improved.

I see that in the first model and the third model I applied layer normalization and both's prediction seems to be very bad....Does layer normalization makes the learning delay? But according to papers like: 
https://www.arxiv-vanity.com/papers/1607.06450/ layer normalization speeds up the training and also helps in speeding the training loss. So, I am really confused. I have limited resources of GPU and I am not sure if I should go for another try without layer normalization.......

Comment: it seems like your third model is not training well. try to change the learning rate.

Comment: I am using the learning scheduler provided by pytorch:

and I call it every time I call the optimizer:
optimizer.step()
scheduler.step()
However, I added 2 convolutional layer before the stacked GRU and the training and  validation loss seems to improve. I even can see some words in few epochs.....